# Kislevite Kossar encumbrance

Tags: encumbrance, wfrp-2e, wfrp

We are planning on starting a new campaign of warhammer fantasy roleplay 2, using the encumbrance rules.
I wanted to play a Kislevite Kossar, but it turns out that the starting equipment seems way to heavy to carry as a new character.

As a Kossar, I'll be starting the game with:

- a great weapon (200),
- a bow and 10 arrows (100),
- a set of medium armour: Mail Coat (80), Leather Jack (50), and Leather Leggings (20)

Plus the stuff given to any new adventurer:

- common clothes (15)
- a dagger (10)
- an hand axe (50)
- a blanket (10) and set of wooden cutlery (2)
  Totalling more than 500 encumbrance.

Meanwhile, as an human, I'm supposed to have between 22 and 40 strength, meaning that my carrying capacity will be between 220 and 400.

As I understand it, I will get between -3 and -4 in movement penalty (-1 for being over my carrying capacity and between -2 and -3 for being more than 100/150 over the limit) so I will most likely be unable to move.

Am I missing something? Or are you supposed to only carry part of your starting equipment?
Is there a way (common houserule or whatever) to play a Kossar while using the encumbrance variant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found an errata to the rule that add a precision to the sturdy talent : "if you are using Encumbrance values with a character who has the sturdy talent ignore the Encumbrance values of the armour worn".
Since human start with two random talents, you may be able to persuade your DM to let you choose sturdy, thus reducing your starting weight by 150, which make the Kossar a lot more playable.

However, my DM couldn't be swayed and since I didn't roll sturdy as my starting talent, I had to abandon my two handed weapon at the start of the adventure in order to move.

Comment: Where can that erratum be found?

Comment: @HeyICanChan we found it on reddit (here : https://www.reddit.com/r/warhammerfantasyrpg/comments/70d89v/errata/), I couldn't find a more official source so I didn't include it in the answer. Do you think I should ?